# How to automap the result set of a custom SQL query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'd like to run raw SQL queries through SQLAlchemy and have the resulting rows use python types which are automatically mapped from the database type.  This AutoMap functionality is available for tables in the database.  Is it available for any arbitrary resultset?

As an example, we build small sqlite database:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Trainer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(50), last_name VARCHAR(50), dob DATE, tiger_skill FLOAT);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Trainer VALUES (1, 'Joe', 'Exotic', '1963-03-05', 0.6)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Trainer VALUES (2, 'Carole', 'Baskin', '1961-06-06', 0.3)")
cur.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

And uing SQLAlchemy, I query the newly created database "test.db":

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")
connection = engine.connect()
CUSTOM_SQL_QUERY = "SELECT count(*) as total_trainers, min(dob) as first_dob from Trainer"
result = connection.execute(CUSTOM_SQL_QUERY)
for r in result:
    print(r)

>>> (2, '1961-06-06')
```

Notice that the second column in the result set is a python string, not a python `datetime.date` object. Is there a way for sqlalchemy to automap an arbitrary result set? Or is this automap reflection capability limited to just actual tables in the database?

Comment: you can use orm instead of plain query

Comment: AFAIK sqlite does not really do datetime, therefore sqlalchemy does not detect it. It should work as you expect with any other RDBMS.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083643/deserializing-json-in-sqlalchemy-when-using-raw-sql, you can use `TextClause.columns()` to manually provide type information.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the response - what if I don't know the types of the columns beforehand because it's provided by a user? Any sqlalchemy-ic way to determine the column types dynamically?