# How can I query a nested array field in a MutableDict column with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My example column data looks like this:

```
{"fieldA": [{"id": 6, "fieldB": "data"}]}
```

The column data type is `MutableDict.as_mutable(JSONAsString)`

JSONAsString is a custom serializer that converts a JSON type to a string and back, so I think it can just be treated as a JSON type. I think the issue may also be that SQLAlchemy doesn't deserialize during a query, so tips on how to do that may help as well.

I would like to query for the `id` field for all `id`s that are in a known list.

How can I do it with SQLAlchemy? Thank you.

Comment: What is `JSONAsString`? Is there a reason why you are not using `JSON` or `JSONB` data types?

Comment: Whoops, I did not realize that was a custom decorator. It's basically a serializer that converts a dictionary into a string form. It deserializes to the `JSON` type though. I'll clarify in the question!

Comment: I think maybe the issue is actually that SQLAlchemy does not deserialize on query. tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083643/deserializing-json-in-sqlalchemy-when-using-raw-sql but it has not worked